# Uncompression error when install Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-cd

I get a Uncompression error when blotting from an Ubuntu LiveCd. My hard disk got corrupted and buying a new system is not an option at the moment, so I need to install Ubuntu on the machine to get it working. The LiveCd is an USB that was just formatted using Universal USB Insatller. The MD5 checksums match and I've tried it two times. Note: I cannot buy any new hardware or any software for that matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried booting another time and I got fixed :)

Comment: I got same error, and rebooting also fixed it)

Comment: Yeah, I got the same one, created bootable USB again and it was fine.